# How to account for aggregation over subjects in meta-analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis

I conduct a small meta-analysis of the preferences ratings for objects in two different conditions. I compute Fisher's z and SE for each study.

1) There are studies with totally different number of trials. For example, there is a study with 24 subjects and 2 trials per subject and a study with the same 24 subjects and 44 trials per subject. How to account for such variability? The formula for SE of z (1/sqrt(n-3)) is inversely dependent on a sample size, but what to consider as a "sample" in such situation? The number of subjects, the number of trials, or a multiplication of both, i.e. the total number of trials per experiment?

2) There are studies that use non-aggregated data. For example, in one study a binomial "like vs. don't like" scale is used and a total amount of "like" and "don't like" answers is reported. To compute z I first compute Cox's d, then transform it and its variance to z and SE of z. The resulting SE of z is quite small in comparison to a value computed using 1/sqrt(n-3). How to correctly include this study in analysis?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that when studies are not designed similarly enough to combine that the best approach to meta-analysis is to get a combined p-value rather than trying to get a single combined z score for a combined test.  This is commonly done when studies address the same characteristics through different types of hypothesis tests. I don't think it makes sense to attempt a combined test approach.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it solves the second problem. However, the problem of aggregation by different amount of trials remains. Same values of subject means, for example, can be obtained from different number of trials, thus leading to identical p-values.

Answer (score -1):

If you believe the studies are clinically homogenous enough to combine but the issue with the multiplicity then you must treat the studies as clusters. For example for each trial your N clusters would be 24 but you also need the intra-class correlation between the repeated tests in each cluster. Most likely you will need to contact the study authors for this information, or preferentially ask for the raw data to perform an individual patient meta-analysis. In both cases, you should seek guidance from a statistician familiar with dealing with cluster trials.

Ahmed